# Cassandra CQL formatter

Tags: cassandra, formatting

I'm looking for a tool that can format CQL schema files in a consistent way.

Ex:

```
CREATE TABLE platforms.provisiondevice ( device_eui text, app_eui text, api_key text, acct_id text, site_id text, status text, PRIMARY KEY ((device_eui, app_eui)));
```

to

```
CREATE TABLE platforms.provisiondevice (
    device_eui text,
    app_eui text,

    api_key text,
    acct_id text,
    site_id text,
    status text,

    PRIMARY KEY ((device_eui, app_eui))
);
```

So far my googling has turned up no results for a CQL formatter. It basically has to be a offline command-line tool to fit my needs.

A SQL formatter could technically work as well if it supports CQL, but none of my google searches for that worked either.

Answer (score 4):

In Datastax Devcenter you can use `ctrl+shift+f` to format the selected cql statement.

OR

Select the statement to format and `rightclick -> source -> format`

Comment: I don't see Datastax Devcenter available for download any more.

Comment: https://academy.datastax.com/downloads... it has devcenter still listed